# Attribute Starts With Selector - CSS Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Not that great at coding, but learning. Wondering if this is possible, can't really find something close enough on sites/forums.

I'm using tampermonkey/greasemonkey with jquery.

Trying to select a specific element that is on every web page for the site, but the first ID tag is random. Trying to just add a Div with the word TEST.

Code I'm trying: `( "<p>Test</p>" ).insertAfter( "div[id^='#highlight_panel_'] > div.efhpContainer > table > tbody > tr > td.efhpLeftContent > div:nth-child(4)" );`

***Edited***
Okay, maybe I made that confusing? lol. Don't care if it is messy(someone asked)

So say I clicked on a link, I get:

```
#highlight_panel_34sdf3e2 > div.efhpContainer > table > tbody > tr > td.efhpLeftContent > div:nth-child(4)
```

Now if I click on a different link, I will get:

```
#highlight_panel_23vs87y334r3rkfi > div.efhpContainer > table > tbody > tr > td.efhpLeftContent > div:nth-child(4)
```

Each link has it's own unique ID.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you care that your code is unreadable?

Comment: I think you mean `div[id^='highlight_panel_']` (no hash)

Comment: Adding a `P` element will never result in appending a `div`

Comment: yeah, andi is right; just take the `#` out of your selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is hard to understand, I think that you need to invest time on refactoring.

By the way, jQuery supports css syntax, so, you can always by "wildcards".
Here is a working example:

```js
function RandomIDCtrl($) {
  
  var tpl = '<div class="js_injected">Test</div>';
  var randomElement = $('[id^="someRandomID_"]');
  var context = $('td > div:nth-child(4)', randomElement);
  
  console.log(context);
  
  $(tpl).insertAfter(context);
}

jQuery(document).ready(RandomIDCtrl);
```

```css
td div {
  min-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

table { width: 100%; }

td div:nth-child(1) { background: green;}
td div:nth-child(2) { background: yellow;}
td div:nth-child(3) { background: blue;}
td div:nth-child(4) { background: lightseagreen;}

.js_injected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="someRandomID_2">

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <div> child 1</div>
        
        <div> child 2</div>
        
        <div> child 3</div>
        
        <div> child 4</div>
          
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I made a change in my question, but will this still work towards it?